# React Js server start failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, npm-start

I am trying to start React Js server by using command **"npm start"** but it is showing following error on console:

```
prateek@localhost:~/WebstormProjects/untitled> npm start

> untitled@0.1.0 start /home/prateek/WebstormProjects/untitled
> react-scripts start

Could not find an open port at localhost.localdomain.
Network error message: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost.localdomain

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! untitled@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the untitled@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output     above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/prateek/.npm/_logs/2017-09-29T05_33_18_507Z-debug.log
```

I am using npm 5.3.0 and node 8.4.0 on Linux.

The npm log file below:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node8', '/usr/bin/npm-default', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~prestart: untitled@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~start: untitled@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib64/node_modules/npm8/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/prateek/WebstormProjects/untitled/node_modules/.bin:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/prateek/WebstormProjects/untitled
10 silly lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle untitled@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: untitled@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm8/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm8/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid untitled@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/prateek/WebstormProjects/untitled
16 verbose Linux 4.11.8-2-default
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node8" "/usr/bin/npm-default" "start"
18 verbose node v8.4.0
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error untitled@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the untitled@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can someone please tell me that how can I fix this error?

Comment: `Could not find an open port at localhost.localdomain.`

Comment: code would be nice.

Comment: @Kevin B Actually, localhost is the name of pc.

Comment: i mean, even if that's the name of the pc (highly unlikely) that's not relevant. The name of the pc has nothing to do with node.js or what domain it should be looking for a port on.

Comment: Why -1 to my post? What's wrong with my post?

Comment: there's not enough information here to solve the problem. it's unclear, poorly researched, both reasons for downvoting. a question that can't be answered isn't useful. Once it's been improved that may change.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will remember it in future and the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

on OpenSUSE, To fix getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost.localdomain error issue, you can try:

Verify that the HOST environment variable is set correctly. You can run **`echo $HOST`** to see its current value. If the value is incorrect or missing, you can set it by running **`export HOST=localhost`** in your terminal.

Comment: Needs more code formatting, as author provides code sample on the answer

Answer (score -1):

It appears like something else is running on the development port for react (port 3000). Run the command `sudo lsof -n -i :3000 | grep LISTEN` and then either close the program that is using the port or use `sudo kill {PID}` (replace {PID} with the PID found using the first command).

Comment: Try using `sudo react-scripts start`